# About javaFX, Need to align a node that is inside a listview to the far right

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I recently picked up "Mastering Javafx 8 Controls by Hendrix Ebbers, and have been messing around creating UI for a couple of days. I am currently learning about list views and i decided to populate a list with nodes that contain labes and buttons.

This book is really good at providiing the reader with tools, but right now i think i have hit a brick wall.

First problem is that I cant seem to find a way to make the list extend to the bottom of the screen.

Second, I need to make the button inside each list line extend to the far right, pretty close to the window frame, just for asthetics.
Is there anything I am missing? I would like to achieve this result without changing the structure I am using. 
Here is the class in question as well as the .css file:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class MainAplicationWindow extends Application{
    VBox vBox1;
    VBox vBox2;
    HBox hBox1;
    HBox hBox2;
    HBox hBox3;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Button button6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

public HBox populateNewSimpleListCell(){
    HBox listCell = new HBox();
    listCell.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    listCell.setSpacing(10);

    VBox labelContainer = new VBox();
    labelContainer.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    labelContainer.setSpacing(10);


    Label nameHere =  new Label("Insert Name Here!");
    Label LastNameHere =  new Label("Insert Last Name Here!");
    Button deleteReccord = new Button("Delete");
    deleteReccord.setOnAction(e-> ConfirmNotificationWindow.display("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to delette?"));

    labelContainer.getChildren().addAll(nameHere, LastNameHere);

    listCell.getChildren().addAll(labelContainer, deleteReccord);
    return listCell;
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // Initializing the containers.
    vBox1 = new VBox();
    vBox1.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    vBox1.setSpacing(10);

    vBox2 = new VBox();
    vBox2.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    vBox2.setSpacing(10);

    hBox1 = new HBox();
    hBox1.setPadding(new Insets(50,50,50,50));
    hBox1.setSpacing(100);

    hBox2 = new HBox();
    hBox2.setPadding(new Insets(50,50,50,50));
    hBox2.setSpacing(100);

    hBox3 = new HBox();

    //initializing the nodes.
    button1 = new Button("Option 1 ");
    button2 = new Button("Option 2 ");
    button3 = new Button("Option 3 ");
    button4 = new Button("Option 4 ");
    button5 = new Button("Option 5 ");
    button6 = new Button("Option 6 ");

    // Events
    button1.setOnAction(e-> SimpleLogInScreen.display("Log in"));
    button2.setOnAction(e-> ConfirmNotificationWindow.display("Log in", "Confirm?"));
    button3.setOnAction(e-> SimpleNotificationWindow.display("Log in", "Alert, invalid action!"));


    // Arrange the containers and contents
    hBox1.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, button3);
    hBox2.getChildren().addAll(button4, button5, button6);

    vBox1.getChildren().addAll(hBox1, hBox2);

    hBox3.getChildren().addAll(vBox1);
    hBox3.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);



    // Creating a list view
    ListView<HBox> list = new ListView<HBox>();

    ObservableList<HBox> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
    for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++){
        items.addAll(populateNewSimpleListCell());
    }
    list.setItems(items);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------



    vBox2.getChildren().addAll(hBox3, list);

    // Loading the final scene.
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(vBox2);
    scene1.getStylesheets().add("StyleSheets.css");

    // Final steps to set up the window.

    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main Aplication Interface");
    primaryStage.setWidth(800);
    primaryStage.setHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

}

The css file:

```
.root{
    -fx-background-color: #383838;
}

.button {
 -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 8;
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #a34313 0%, #903b12 100%),
        #9d4024,
        #d86e3a,
        radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #d86e3a, #c54e2c);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
}

.text-field {
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
    -fx-font-color: black;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-background-color: #dc9656;
    -fx-background-radius: 8;
}

.label {
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
    -fx-text-fill: #dc9656;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.list{

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the first part of the question: when I run this the list goes all the way to the bottom of the window. Or are you just meaning that maximizing the window is not working?

Comment: the list doesnt extend to the bottom of the window, there is a thick black space at the bottom.

Comment: You set padding on the vbox that contains it...

Comment: @James_D care to elaborate more, that does not seem to work.

Comment: You have `vbox2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));`. The space you see is just that padding. Remove it and you remove the space. (What did you think that line did, out of interest?)

Comment: @james, its true, thank you. Now i was able to move the button to the right using that, however whenever the strings are of diferent size the button won remain in the same place, any way i can let it stay put regardless of the lenght of the strings in the left?

Comment: To do that you need to use something more appropriate than an `HBox`, such as a `GridPane` or `AnchorPane`. However, since you have made the type of your `ListView` an `HBox`, you will need to change a lot of your code to make this work. Usinga `Node` type as the data type for a `ListView` is generally a big mistake, and you should restructure this to use a genuine data type and use a `cellFactory` to configure the cell, but you said you don't want to change the structure of the application (even thought it's completely wrong). So I'm not sure how to help with the rest.

Comment: @james By no means I want to stick to some code if it means that I am doing things the wrong way. Please any pointer is always welcome, besides this is a learning process, and i like to learn to do thigns the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap you see between the bottom of the list and the bottom of the window is simply the padding you set on the `VBox` containing the list:

```
vBox2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

If you remove this, you remove the gap. You can also just remove the portion at the bottom:

```
vBox2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));
```

To get the buttons over to the right is possible but quite difficult in a `HBox`. It's better to use a layout more appropriate to doing this, such as a `GridPane` or `AnchorPane`. To make this change, you would have to change the type of your `ListView` (which you have made a `ListView<HBox>`) and consequently the type of your `ObservableList`, etc.

In fact, it is generally a very bad idea to make the *data* type of a `ListView` (or other such control) a type of `Node`. (I have not read Hendrick's book, but I've read other things he has written and I'd be pretty astonished if he did anything like this in his book.) You should create an appropriate data type to hold the *data* in the `ListView`. If you need to change the way it is displayed, use the `cellFactory` and create the appropriate `ListCell`s.

Since your data seems to comprise a first name and a last name for each item, I'll call the data class a `Person` class (though in your actual application something like `User`, `Employee`, `Customer`, or `Student`, etc, might be more appropriate). It can be as simple as this:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName ;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName ;
        this.lastName = lastName ;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


}
```

or you may find it better to use the [JavaFX Property pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) to implement this class.

The list cell can then look like this (using a `GridPane` and column constraints to align each column appropriately):

```
public class PersonCell extends ListCell<Person> {
    private final Label firstNameLabel ;
    private final Label lastNameLabel ;

    private final GridPane listCellContents ;

    public PersonCell() {
        listCellContents = new GridPane();
        listCellContents.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        listCellContents.setHgap(10);
        listCellContents.setVgap(10);

        firstNameLabel = new Label();
        lastNameLabel = new Label();

        Button deleteReccord = new Button("Delete");
        deleteReccord.setOnAction(e -> { 
            Person person = getItem();
            getListView().getItems().remove(person);
        });


        listCellContents.add(firstNameLabel, 0, 0);
        listCellContents.add(lastNameLabel, 0, 1);
        listCellContents.add(deleteReccord, 1, 0, 1, 2);

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();

        rightCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        listCellContents.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            firstNameLabel.setText(item.getFirstName());
            lastNameLabel.setText(item.getLastName());
            setGraphic(listCellContents);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your list view setup looks like:

```
    ListView<Person> list = new ListView<>();

    ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        items.add(new Person("First Name "+i, "Last Name "+i));
    }
    list.setItems(items);

    list.setCellFactory(lv -> new PersonCell());
```

Here is a complete SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApplicationWindow extends Application {
    VBox vBox1;
    VBox vBox2;
    HBox hBox1;
    HBox hBox2;
    HBox hBox3;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Button button6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class PersonCell extends ListCell<Person> {
        private final Label firstNameLabel ;
        private final Label lastNameLabel ;

        private final GridPane listCellContents ;

        public PersonCell() {
            listCellContents = new GridPane();
            listCellContents.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            listCellContents.setHgap(10);
            listCellContents.setVgap(10);

            firstNameLabel = new Label();
            lastNameLabel = new Label();

            Button deleteReccord = new Button("Delete");
            deleteReccord.setOnAction(e -> { 
                Person person = getItem();
                System.out.println("Delete "+person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName());
            });


            listCellContents.add(firstNameLabel, 0, 0);
            listCellContents.add(lastNameLabel, 0, 1);
            listCellContents.add(deleteReccord, 1, 0, 1, 2);

            ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
            ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();

            rightCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
            rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

            listCellContents.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                firstNameLabel.setText(item.getFirstName());
                lastNameLabel.setText(item.getLastName());
                setGraphic(listCellContents);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Initializing the containers.
        vBox1 = new VBox();
        vBox1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vBox1.setSpacing(10);

        vBox2 = new VBox();
        vBox2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));
        vBox2.setSpacing(10);

        hBox1 = new HBox();
        hBox1.setPadding(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));
        hBox1.setSpacing(100);

        hBox2 = new HBox();
        hBox2.setPadding(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));
        hBox2.setSpacing(100);

        hBox3 = new HBox();

        // initializing the nodes.
        button1 = new Button("Option 1 ");
        button2 = new Button("Option 2 ");
        button3 = new Button("Option 3 ");
        button4 = new Button("Option 4 ");
        button5 = new Button("Option 5 ");
        button6 = new Button("Option 6 ");

        // Events
        button1.setOnAction(e -> /*SimpleLogInScreen.display("Log in")*/ System.out.println("Log in"));
        button2.setOnAction(e -> /*ConfirmNotificationWindow.display("Log in",
                "Confirm?")*/ System.out.println("Confirm"));
        button3.setOnAction(e -> /*SimpleNotificationWindow.display("Log in",
                "Alert, invalid action!")*/ System.out.println("Notify"));

        // Arrange the containers and contents
        hBox1.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, button3);
        hBox2.getChildren().addAll(button4, button5, button6);

        vBox1.getChildren().addAll(hBox1, hBox2);

        hBox3.getChildren().addAll(vBox1);
        hBox3.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        // Creating a list view
        ListView<Person> list = new ListView<>();

        ObservableList<Person> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add(new Person("Insert first name here", "Insert last name here"));
        }
        list.setItems(items);

        list.setCellFactory(lv -> new PersonCell());


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------

        vBox2.getChildren().addAll(hBox3, list);

        VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Loading the final scene.
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(vBox2);
        scene1.getStylesheets().add("main-application-window.css");

        // Final steps to set up the window.

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Main Aplication Interface");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static class Person {
        private String firstName ;
        private String lastName ;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName ;
            this.lastName = lastName ;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I will go over this and implement it as such in my project. As always, your answers are always very insightful.

Comment: I know this question is solved already, but i wonder, what to do if i want to delete items from the list now? Where are these items stored?

Comment: They are stored in the `ListView`'s `items` list (after all, you put them there with `list.setItems(...)`). So you can do `list.getItems().remove(...)`. See update.

Comment: Awesome, youre the best. I am lightyears away fromt this code yet.